# Unable to query from a different DB

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two identical databases, one containing data related to year1 and the other containing data related to year2.
in both databases I have a table which joins product data and customer data into one query called "Data_Details".
Now if I run the following from within the same database

```
Select * FROM Data_Details;
```

Everything works as expected, but if I run it from the other Db

```
SELECT *
FROM Data_Details IN 'path_to_my_db/Database.accdb';
```

I get a 'wrong type' error message.
I have tried removing fields from the query, to check where the issue was lying but I realized that I am able to retrieve data from the other db as long as the Data_Details query is a simple SELECT query;as soon as I add a Join to it, no matter what, I am no more able to retrieve anything from it from another DB while it works perfectly if I run it from the same DB.

Comment: It seems like you have two different data types in the two dbs. In ant case, a linked table might be better.

Comment: I have checked and data types are identical,  but still even if I had different datatypes, why should it complain? I am just getting data from a query that works on the other db...I don't understand.

Comment: Please show us your path. Is it a networked drive or CPU hard disk drive? Where do these databases reside relative to each other?  As reminder, never use Access in internet folders or flash drives.

Comment: I think that your problem lies in trying to refer to a query, rather than a table. Can you link the relevant tables and recreate the query?

Comment: @Parfait Both databases are in the same directory, local hard drive.

Comment: @Fionnuala But I can get data properly from the Data_Details which is a query, just as long as I don't add a JOIN to it. I really don't understand, as soon as Data_Details performs a Join it stops working (when called from the outside, but keeps working if I have it running from the same Db)

Answer (score 0):

It should read:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [d:\folder\database.accdb].Data_Details
```

But why not just link that table?

Comment: Tried but same result.
I have also tried to link the table, but when I choose the origin (that is the previous year database) I can pick only tables as sources and not queries or other linked tables,

Comment: That is true. You can only reference/link the tables in/from a database file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was causing the problem.

My Data_Details query was joining two tables, one of those was a linked table referring to a csv sheet.
There was probably something wrong in the csv as everything started to work fine as soon as I replaced it with an xlsx file.

Thank you for you help and your time.